# Flutter plugin: Android studio doesn't detect connected devices

Tags: android-studio, flutter

It shows  and when clicked a drop down always shows "Loading...", but nothing ever gets detected.

Even though adb detects the device.

Comment: Not a super answer **but I simply restarted Android Studio**. (My problem was: `flutter devices` listed my device, but Android Studio couldn't find it).

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267109/flutter-emulator-launched-but-not-detected-by-android-studio/53557131#53557131

Answer (score 1):

Setting the **correct path for "Flutter SDK path"** under "Languages & Frameworks/Flutter" in Android Studio settings fixed the problem.

I had installed two flutter copies, the old one was dirty and not working. But I hadn't updated the path for the new copy in Android Studio.

#### Edit

It's always good to run `flutter doctor`, when in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - make sure you enable USB Debugging in Developer Options on your device

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it was solved reformating my pubspec.yaml file (I had a identation issue)

Comment: Please describe how you fixed/what you did to fix your indentation issue. Even though people who create .yaml files should probably know, it might prove helpful for someone to know exactly how you fixed the problem in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the comments posted here helped me. After trying many things, I noticed that I had an unstable flutter version by running `flutter version`, I changed then to a stable version (at the time this post was written it was version 1.17.3) by executing `flutter version 1.17.3`, then I restarted android studio and flutter finally had recognised my device

Answer (score -1):

you just need to set your android sdk path for the flutter using this command :

```
flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/Sdk
```

and you can get your sdk path(/path/to/Sdk) using this command :

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```