# <Flutter> emulator launched but not detected by android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, flutter

I'm a beginner in Flutter and I've an emulator opened/powered on and android studio doesn't detect it.

[image]

Hence I can't run any program because "no device is running". I've tried installing 'Android emulator' in the SDK tools but android studio still cant detect it.

Comment: Did you run emulator by cmd?

Comment: By cmd or through AS it's the same thing

Comment: Is the emulator phone booted and running a supported api level for the app? Also, is it the same problem for all your android studio projects?

Comment: In Android Studio terminal. adb kill-server then adb start-server fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem.

```
CMD: flutter devices
No devices detected.

CMD: device emulators
Device emulator-5554 is offline.
```

In Android virtual device manager, I cold boot emulator and it started working.

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio device list shows "**loading**" and no devices connected. Thus, I opened emulator but I cannot run flutter on emulator on Android Studio. After 5 hours I found that the reason is the new Flutter version.

*I solved with choose different version of Dart and Flutter!*

You need to download ***1.17.3*** version. Quick download link: [Dowloand Flutter SDK 1.17.3 Version](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/stable/macos/flutter_macos_1.17.3-stable.zip)

> And switch **Stable Channel & Dart: 2.8.4**, this is important. Also, if you want, you can check all versions of Flutter SDK: [Flutter Versions](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos)

*On MacOS, just write terminal: flutter channel stable*

> **Note:** *If this answer is not working for you, you can open android module of your flutter app in Android Studio. It can be helpful when you try to add Firebase skills.*

Comment: Can confirm this works on:
Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020,
macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: @SnuKies I am using same

Answer (score 1):

In a windows platform I did:

If you have ran `flutter doctor` and there is no issues and if you can run your flutter app in cmd or using VSCode:

Just try to open Android Studio or IntelliJ as administrator by right clicking on the icon. This may list down devices and solve your problem.

The reason may be you have cloned flutter repository or you don't have right permission in flutter installed directory.

Comment: Thank you very much !!! :-)
I've been looking for hours something to solve my problem, this was the solution "run as admin" !!

Comment: So I need to open Android Studio everytime as administrator?

Comment: @NullByte08 No, you can do everything by cmd if you do not prefer that way

Answer (score 0):

Run **flutter doctor** command to check whats the problem.

In terminal, run the **flutter devices** command to verify that Flutter recognizes your connected Android device.
Check your flutter plugin whether it is up to date.

And read this [flutter run: No connected devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices) , You may find the solution.

Comment: I did everything said on that article and it doesn't work either

Comment: Is it run for android project ? If yes, something wrong with flutter. And if no, try to re-install android studio.

Answer (score 0):

For me (on a Mac) I had the Android SDK installed in a custom location so I needed to set the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable. In the terminal you can check what this value is with:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

I added the Android SDK to my `.bash_profile` (might be a different file if you are using Linux or Windows) for both `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH`.

```
# already had these
export PATH="$PATH":"/opt/android-sdk/tools"
export PATH="$PATH":"/opt/flutter-sdk/bin"

# added this
export ANDROID_HOME="/opt/android-sdk"
```

Replace `/opt/android-sdk` with wherever yours is.

Then I updated the variables with

```
source .bash_profile
```

Testing with flutter doctor showed it was working.

```
flutter doctor
```

I restarted Android Studio and the emulator worked.

Answer (score 0):

The last version of Flutter 1.17.5 (release the 2th, July) solved this issue for me.
Just `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

run `Flutter doctor` to make sure you install everything.

run `Flutter devices` to see whether it is detected by flutter or not.

if you can find the your emulator there run `flutter run -d <YOUR_EMULATOR_ID>`

if you unable to find your emulator there may be you have to accept the android licenses . run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept.

run `flutter emulators`  to see list of emulators you have.

run `flutter emulators --launch <emulator id>` to launch

run `Flutter devices` to check whether emulator is detected by flutter or not.

run `flutter run -d <YOUR_DEVICE_ID>`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is, updating **Android Emulator**.

- Visit **SDK Manager**
- Check whether any updates available for **Android Emulator**
- If available, install the newest version

Hope this would be helpful!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Android Studio.

I had an emulator but it was not recognized even though the emulator was open.

I got around this by launching developer mode inside of the actual emulator by following the steps in this link:  [https://tweaklibrary.com/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-android/#:~:text=How%20to%20Enable%20Developer%20Options%20On%20Android.%201,one%20of%20the%20most%20powerful%20...%20More%20items](https://tweaklibrary.com/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-android/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Enable%20Developer%20Options%20On%20Android.%201,one%20of%20the%20most%20powerful%20...%20More%20items)

After setting the emulator to developer mode, the emulator phone appeared as an option and when I ran the flutter hello world it appeared on the emulator.