# Flutter only recognizing edge(web) as a connected device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-virtual-device

so I have recently started using flutter and the problem I am facing is with the devices. When i run flutter devices in the terminal it shows the following:

```
1 connected device:

Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 85.0.564.67
```

I have configured an Android Emulator in the Android Studio AVD but it does not work. Also the emulator lags alot. Can someone help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<Flutter> emulator launched but not detected by android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51267109/flutter-emulator-launched-but-not-detected-by-android-studio)

Comment: no it doesn't, i tried going through all the steps of about 3 answers but still nothing